# Corrupting database

Tags: database, linux

What is the best way to corrupt a database?

In order to test recovery procedures for databases, one need a corrupted database. What is the best way of corrupting a database on purpose?

The database I intend to test is a Berkeley DB, running on Linux, in an embedded environment.

Comment: Make random changes to the underlying data?

Answer (score 1):

What are you expecting to result in database corruption? There are different possible sources of corruption and they probably show up differently:

1. complete hard disc failure
2. unreliable hard disc (broken sectors, slow error handling code triggered)
3. RAM corruption
4. DBMS bugs
5. database client bugs
6. viruses/trojans intentionally effecting the database
7. more things that I forgot

Just switching random bits/byte in the storage file does not cover all of those.

Comment: My focus in the test is bugs in my client application, and recovery needed due to power failure.

Comment: why don't you just unplug the power cord?

Comment: This is also what I do now. But it takes a lot of reboots to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

this will corrupt your DB file really good

```
dd if=/dev/random of=/pathto/your.db bs=`du -b /pathto/your.db|awk '{print $1}'` count=1 conv=notrunc
```

- wanted to add as a comment but formatter parses out stuff